# Web-scraper for housing web

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I've made a program that scrapes a famous spanish web of housing ads. The program is formed by two big classes: a Manager, that goes through the list of ads and saves their links in a list, and a class that parses each ad and stores some values into a database (as the price or the number of bedrooms).

I have another auxiliar class, called `Annon_Browser`, that uses the module `requests` to download different urls. It swaps between differents proxyes and user-agents to annonimize the search.

I am especially about the way I have handled parallelism. While I have protected the database behind a lock to prevent race conditions, right now I am using exceptions to kill my threads, which I guess is not best practice. I'm also afraid of a memory leak somewhere because of the abrupt termination of the threads.

```
import logging
import random
import re
import requests
import threading
import time
import web2 as web_tools

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from sqlobject import *

DB_LOCK = threading.Lock()
logger = ''


class ThreadEnd(Exception):
    pass


class WebCrawlerManager(object):
    def __init__(self, create_table=False):
        """
        Connects to a SQL database. If specified, table is created from scratch
        :param create_table: Sets if a new SQL table is to be created.
        """
        logger.info("[+] Crawler up. Table creation:{}".format(create_table))
        sqlhub.processConnection = connectionForURI("mysql://root:root@localhost/fotocasa")
        logger.info("[+] Connected to MySQL server")

        if create_table:
            WebCrawlerFotocasa.CasaMadrid.createTable()
            logger.info("[*] Table successfully created")
        self.main_loop()

    @staticmethod
    def get_number_pages(web):
        """
        Parses the number of pages to be read.
        :param web: [str] html to be parsed.
        :return: [int] number of pages to be read.
        """
        num_pages = web.findAll('a', {"class": "sui-Pagination-link"})[-2].get_text()
        num_pages = int(num_pages.replace('.', ''))
        return num_pages

    def main_loop(self):
        processed = 0

        # Import and parse main web.
        url_fotocasa = "http://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/casas/madrid-capital/todas-las-zonas/l/"
        web = web_tools.Annon_Browser(url_fotocasa)
        web = BeautifulSoup(web, 'html5lib')

        number_of_pages = self.get_number_pages(web)

        index = 1

        while index < number_of_pages:
            urls = []
            logger.info("[+] Entering main loop. Page:{}/{} Processed until now: {}".format(index, number_of_pages, processed))

            try:
                web = requests.get(url_fotocasa).content
            except Exception:
                logger.critical("Impossible to retrieve URLs. Going to sleep and trying later.")
                time.sleep(random.randrange(20, 30))
                continue

            web = BeautifulSoup(web, 'html5lib')
            web = web.findAll('a', {"class": "re-Card-title"})
            logger.info("[+] Urls retrieved: {}".format(len(web)))
            processed += len(web)

            for x in web:
                x = 'http:' + x['href']
                urls.append(x)

            for count, x in enumerate(urls):
                threading.Thread(target=WebCrawlerFotocasa, args=(x, count)).start()
            dormir = random.randint(5, 20)
            logger.info('[*] Página acabada. Durmiendo durante: {} segundos'.format(dormir))
            time.sleep(dormir)
            if len(web) == 0:
                index -= 1
            index += 1
            url_fotocasa = "http://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/casas/espana/todas-las-zonas/l/{}".format(index)


class WebCrawlerFotocasa(object):
    """Descarga un html correspondiente a un enlace de fotocasa. Lo parsea y lo escribe en la base de datos"""
    LABELS = ('ad_title', 'city', 'county', 'city_zone', 'mts2', 'neighbourhood', 'postal_code', 'price',
              'price_max', 'price_min', 'property', 'bathrooms', 'create_date', 'transaction', 'zone1',
              'propertyfeature', 'oasenergeticcert', 'oasantiquity', 'oasheating', 'conservation', 'lat', 'lng',
              'rooms', 'ad_id')

    class CasaMadrid(SQLObject):
        """
        Definición de la base de datos-
        """
        ad_id = IntCol()
        ad_title = StringCol(length=300)
        city = StringCol(length=50, default=None)
        county = StringCol(length=50, default=None)
        city_zone = StringCol(length=100, default=None)
        mts2 = IntCol()
        bathrooms = IntCol()
        rooms = IntCol()
        price = StringCol(length=1000)
        lat = FloatCol(default=None)
        lng = FloatCol(default=None)
        postal_code = IntCol(default=None)
        features = StringCol(length=200, default=None)
        transaction = StringCol(length=30, default=None)
        create_date = DateCol(default=None)
        zone = StringCol(length=50, default=None)
        neighbourhood = StringCol(length=50, default=None)
        price_min = IntCol(default=None)
        price_max = IntCol(default=None)
        conservacion = StringCol(length=50, default=None)
        property1 = StringCol(length=50, default=None)
        last_date = DateCol()

    def __init__(self, url, count):
        """ Downloads html and creates a Beautiful soup object """
        self.DONE = False
        self.url = url
        self.count = count
        self.data = dict()

        logger.info("[{}] Into thread".format(count))

        web = False
        while not web:
            web = web_tools.Annon_Browser(url)
            logger.info("[{}] Attempting to get url.".format(count))
        logger.info("[{}] Web reached. Parsing data".format(count))
        web = BeautifulSoup(web, 'html5lib')
        web.prettify()

        self.get_data(web)
        self.write_data()

    def get_data(self, web):
        """Parses labels into dict"""

        # titulo vivienda
        self.data['ad_title'] = web.findAll(
            'h1', {"class": "property-title"})[0].get_text().strip()
        self.data['last_date'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        re1 = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s*?:\s*?("[\w\d\s,-\\]*")')
        re2 = re.compile(r'("\w*")\s*?:\s*?("[w,-|]*")')
        residual_data = web.findAll("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})

        text_residual_data = ''
        for x in residual_data:
            text_residual_data += str(x)

        residual_data = re.findall(
            re1, text_residual_data) + re.findall(re2, text_residual_data)

        for x, y in residual_data:
            x = x.strip('"')
            if x == 'price':
                self.data[x] = '{},{};'.format(
                    str(y), time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

            elif x == 'create_date':
                y = y.strip('"')
                dia, mes, año = y.split('/')
                self.data[x] = '{}-{}-{}'.format(año[:4], mes, dia)

            elif x in WebCrawlerFotocasa.LABELS:
                y = y.strip('"')
                y = y.strip(' ')

                try:
                    y = int(y)
                except:
                    pass
                if x == 'property':
                    x = 'property1'
                if y:
                    self.data[x] = y

        logger.info("[{}] Data parsed. Labels parsed".format(self.count, len(self.data)))
        return

    def write_data(self):
        try:
            WebCrawlerFotocasa.CasaMadrid(**self.data)
        except TypeError:
            logger.warning("[!{}]Lacking critical information. URL = {}".format(self.count, self.url))
            raise Exception
        if DB_LOCK.acquire(timeout=100):
            DB_LOCK.release()
            logger.info("[{}] Data saved into database".format(self.count))
            logger.info("[{}] Web data retrieved. Killing thread".format(self.count))
            raise ThreadEnd


def __main__():
    global logger
    FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename="logger2.txt")
    logger = logging.getLogger('web_crawler')
    logger.setLevel(10)
    WebCrawlerManager(create_table=True)


__main__()
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me comment on the web-scraping part specifically without touching the "threading" and "memory" related issues:

- switch from `html5lib` to `lxml` for faster HTML parsing
- instead of using `requests.get(url_fotocasa)` for all the requests in the main loop - [initialize a `Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and reuse - under the hood `requests` will reuse the same TCP connection which would result into a performance boost
- use [`SoupStrainer` class to parse only the desired parts of the document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document)

Overall, I am afraid you are reinventing what [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) offers from out-of-the-box - switching to it would help to remove a lot of boilerplate threading and mysql lock related code, make the project more modular having the data processing and pipelining part defined separately in a clear and modular manner.